# Definitive website or pdf that explains about linux?

Tags: linux

like what is X windows,Cygwin,file system

Comment: Cygwin is not linux. X Window system is also not Linux (it also exists on OS X, though poorly, and possibly on Windows too).

Comment: This is a very broad (and not-programming-related) question. Is there any one part of Linux you wanted to know about? For the record, the best explanations of Linux can be found by typing your question in Google.

Comment: Voting to close, not programming related.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: The examples the OP gives of X Windows and Cygwin, just go to show  that the OP needs to learn about Linux/Unix. He is clearly not looking for something in particular as much as an overall resource to begin to understand Linux.

Comment: @Rober Gould: Is there any one overall resource for understanding Linux/Unix? I learned most of it in little pieces every so often when I needed it (or sometimes after I needed it).

Comment: @Chris Lutz; Nope there isn't anything like that but Olafur's answer does point to a decent beginners resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you have to choose which Linux distribution you wish to use/learn, then you just  use that distro's documentation, which normally has allot info.

You can find here some linux beginner lessons: http://www.linux.org/lessons/beginner/toc.html

Finally the best way to learn, besides reading is "getting your hands dirty". Install a distro of your choice and mess with it :)

Comment: Getting my hands dirty is definitely how I learned - you install it, fiddle, wonder how to do something, search, and learn :)

Answer (score 2):

[I think this is a great way to start](http://www.linux.com/whatislinux/)